# iPhone NSNumberFormatter crash

Tags: iphone, crash

I want to format a NSDecimalNumber as a Dollars value ($1.50) but Im getting a crash.

This is my method:

```
+(NSString*) formatPriceForUser:(NSDecimalNumber*)dPrice{

NSNumberFormatter *formatter;


if (!formatter) { 
    formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:6];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
} 
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromNumber:dPrice];
return str; 
}
```

The crash happens on the stringFromNumber invocation.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Gonso

Comment: Are you seeing an error in console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initializing the local variable `formatter`, so it's getting initialized with whatever garbage is left on the stack, and the initial `if (!formatter)` test is failing.  In C/C++/Objective-C, stack variables are NOT automatically initialized to zero.  The fix is to explicitly initialize `formatter` to `nil`:

```
static NSNumberFormatter *formatter = nil;
```

Also note that by declaring it as `static`, it will persist across function calls, so you avoid reinitializing it for every call.

Comment: static variables *do* get initialized to nil, actually (as of C99). Only local variables don't. The fix is simply to declare it as static, or to use a new formatter every time (which equally relieves the need to initialize it).